Book suggestion in singularly perturbed ODE problem seems to be wrong?
I am working on problem 2.2b from the book Introduction to Perturbation Methods by Holmes. It states: $\epsilon y'' + e^x y' + \epsilon y = 1$ for $0 < x < 1$, where $y(0) = 0$ and $y(1) = 1$. In section 2.2.7 they hint that for this problem the standard assumption that $y \sim y_0 + \epsilon y_1 + ...$ would not work for this problem, so I've first opted for the expansion $y \sim a(\epsilon) y_0 + \ldots$ as they suggested.
Then for the outer solution, one would get for the lowest order (which is $\mathcal{O}(a(\epsilon))$) the equation $e^x y_0' = 1, y_0(1) = 0$, which yields $y_0(x) = (-e^{-x} + e^{-1})$. For the inner solution, we set $\bar{x} = \frac{x}{\epsilon^\alpha}$ to obtain the equation $\epsilon^{1-2 \alpha} Y_0'' + \epsilon^{-\alpha} Y_0' + \bar{x} Y_0' + \epsilon Y_0 = 1$ (where I have expanded using the assumption that $Y \sim Y_0 + ...$ and used $e^{\epsilon^\alpha \bar{x}} \sim 1 + \epsilon^\alpha \bar{x}$). We then find a leading balance of the first two terms leading to $\alpha = 1$. Then we get for order $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ the following: $Y_0'' + Y_0' = 1, Y_0(0) = 0$, which has as solution $c(e^{-\bar{x}} - 1)$.
Then we get to matching, where we use the limit criterion $\lim_{x \to 0}y_0 = \lim_{\bar{x} \to \infty}Y_0$. From this we obtain that $c = 1 - e^{-1}$. But we then have no way to determine what $a(\epsilon)$ should be. Or if the full expansion should have been taken in the limit criterion (so that we get $\lim_{x \to 0} a(\epsilon) y_0 = \lim_{\bar{x} \to \infty}Y_0$, we would obtain $a(\epsilon) = 1$, which would then render our treatment of the outer limit wrong since we then should have used $y_0(1) = 1$ rather than $y_0(1) = 0$ because now the boundary value and the expansion for $y$ are of the same order.
Had we taken $y \sim y_0 + ...$ as you would normally do, we get $y_0  = -e^{-x} + 1 + e^{-1}$. The treatment of $Y_0$ stays the same, but the constant $c$ now becomes $c = -e^{-1}$. There seems to me nothing wrong with this outcome and it seems to line up with my numerical approximation. Therefore I am left wondering why they would suggest in 2.2.7 to use an expansion that leads to a wrong outcome.
